# Email Audit API / Mialbox Dump Request : Are the mailbox download included in the quota?

Tags: google-email-audit-api

We programatically limited our use of the Email Audit API to 800 requests / day (using US/Pacific timezone), but we still meet DeadlineExceeded errors.

Do the mailbox download (HTTP GET to the urls provided by the API) count in the quota ? Or can we download as many mailboxes as we want ?

Is there a way to request more quota ?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Email Audit API limits 100 mailbox export request per day.  I don't think downloading the mailbox or checking the status of the mailbox export counts toward the quota.  The quota is only for the number of requests you can submit per day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of our developpers has run some tests and it turns out the number of of status check is still limited to 1000. It's more than 100 but it would be worth documenting.

We are going to test the downloads quota too.